# XmlSerializer not serializing custom type

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization

I am trying to serialize by following code

```
var data = argsPerCall.ToArray();
var knownTypes = new[] { typeof(int), typeof(int),  
                         typeof(string), typeof(McPosition)};

var serializer = new XmlSerializer(data.GetType(), knownTypes);
// Writing the file requires a TextWriter.
var myStreamWriter = new StreamWriter(filename);
serializer.Serialize(myStreamWriter, data);
myStreamWriter.Close();
```

I am having an issue with `McPosition` type.

For following input

```
5 , 1, "R251" , {1,2,3}
```

I am getting following serialization

```
<ArrayOfAnyType>
    <anyType xsi:type="xsd:int">5</anyType>
    <anyType xsi:type="xsd:int">1</anyType>
    <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">R251</anyType>
    <anyType xsi:type="McPosition" />
  </ArrayOfAnyType>
```

Any idea why it wasnt serialized correctly ?

EDIT:

```
public struct McPosition : IComparable<McPosition> {
    private readonly int _station;
    private readonly int _slot;
    private readonly int _subslot;


    public static McPosition Empty = new McPosition(-1, -1, -1);


    public McPosition(int station, int slot, int subslot) {
      _station = station;
      _slot    = slot;
      _subslot = subslot;
    }
```

etc....

Thanks .

Comment: And what does `McPosition` look like?

Comment: Can you show us your definition of the `McPosition` type please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To be serializeable via `XmlSerializer`, each property on a type **must** have a public getter and setter (and not be marked `[XmlIgnore]` nor have a `ShouldSerialize*()` that returns false, etc). Public fields are also serialized (as long as they aren't `readonly`), but exposing fields is even less desirable. `XmlSerializer` never looks at private members.

I'm ***guessing*** (edit: now confirmed by the updated question) that `McPosition` is an immutable vector, without public setters. That won't work. Options:

- implement `IXmlSerializable` (not overly nice, to be honest)
- add public setters to `McPosition`
- use a separate DTO that is fully mutable

Answer (score 2):

You must add public getter and setter for XML serializable fields. Here : Station, Slot and Subslot.